# SQL Query wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

SQL query

find me all the post tags with the proper count for all the posts under the current category?

example

culture ( culture is the current category name and it has 3 posts associated with it )

culture
   post1    post 1 happens to be associated with tag1, tag3
   post2    post 2 happens to be associated with tag1
   post3    post 3 happens to be associated with tag1, tag4

As a result of the SQL query I'm looking for, I want to get a list as follows

culture
   tag1 (3 posts)
   tag3 ( 1 post )
   tag4 ( 1 post )

and when you click tag1, we get only those (3) posts who have been classified under culture category and that has been tagged as tag1.

I'd like to get this data on the fly when I'm serving the culture page? I know it's an expensive query for run time purposes, but if you leave this aspect aside, how do you do it? will I have to use the wp_query?

Comment: What is the table structure that holds the posts and tags?

Comment: my mistake. I was strictly talking about wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
mysql> select category.category, count(posts.id) from posts join category on
     posts.category=category.id group by posts.category;
+----------+-----------------+
| category | count(posts.id) |
+----------+-----------------+
| tag1     |               3 |
| tag2     |               2 |
| tag3     |               1 |
+----------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```